# How to change UIImagePickerController search bar's background color

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

How to change UIImagePickerController search bar's background color after it present. By default the background color of search bar is transparent, make it looked weird when there are content behind it.

iOS Version: 14.8

[image: image picker]
[image]